# Is there a public list anywhere of people who have signed the Canonical Contributor Agreement?

Tags: canonical

I know there are lists of Ubuntu Members and rankings of people contributing to the 5-a-day project, but I was wondering if there is a record of signatories of the Canonical Contributor Agreement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes](https://launchpad.net/~contributor-agreement-canonical/+members#active); people who have gone through the [contributor agreement process](http://www.canonical.com/contributors) are active members of that group.